# how create vmware services in sprint tool suite

Tags: spring, vmware-server

I create VMware server in sprint tool suite but it has error here:

```
The Tomcat installation directory is not valid. It is missing expected file or folder tcruntime-ctl.sh.
```

[image]

how can I fix it ?